# Odoo warehouse Scan the bar code of the package to record the number of items it contains

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, packaging, warehouse

I want to know if the functionality that I imagine exists with Odoo. I have a product, "Pen" which had the barcode : 111122223333.

I have first type of packaging : Package A 50 pens, who had the barcode 111122223350.

Second type of packaging : Box of 20 packages A who had the barcode 111122221000.

If I receive a delivery of 50000 pens, in boxes, and I scan the barcode of the boxes (I use Odoo 8, and I use the interface of reception), nothing happens, if I scan a pen the quantity starts to appear.

I want to know if Odoo can manage this maneuver or am I obliged to empty my packaging and pass my products one by one ??

Comment: You have to manually developed that. Default is not supported.